# Leave a wake of dead cells behind you

Tags: code-challenge, cellular-automata, game-of-life

[Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is a well known cellular automaton "played" on an infinite grid, filled with cells that are either alive or dead. Once given an initial state, the board evolves according to rules indefinitely. Those rules are:

- Any live cell with 2 or 3 living neighbours (the 8 cells immediately around it) lives to the next state
- Any dead cell with exactly 3 living neighbours becomes a living cell
- Any other cell becomes a dead cell

Game of Life is known for having simple rules yet structures can quickly become chaotic with minimal change.

Consider the following initial state:

[image]

That is, `TNB` made up of live cells. Each letter has a \$5\times7\$ bounding box, with an empty column in between, for a \$16\times7\$ overall bounding box

After 96 generations, it reaches the following state:

[image]

From this point, no meaningful change will happen: there is 1 still life and 1 oscillator which does not interact with the still life.

Now, let's place 2 \$9\times9\$ "areas" on either side:

[image]

You are to place up to \$81\$ living cells in the red area in a configuration \$C\$, so that, when run, there is at least one generation (the **target generation**) for which the following is true:

- The red box is empty (i.e. consists of \$81\$ dead cells)
- The configuration in the blue box is equal to \$C\$
- All other cells on the board are dead.

For example, let's assume your starting configuration \$C\$ is

[image]

Then, for this to be a valid answer, the following state would have to be reached by at least 1 generation:

[image]

<sup>(and there's no other living cells on the board)</sup>

What the board looks like before and after the target generation is irrelevant, so long as at least one generation meets these conditions.

Your score is equal to the number of living cells in \$C\$, aiming for fewer cells, with ties being broken by fewest generations until the target generation.

[Here](https://copy.sh/life/?gist=33a2995056bd5be6613f28c17db94ba4) is a pre-loaded grid with the red and blue areas outlined

---

If this is impossible, I will also accept a proof of impossibility as a valid answer

Comment: 2^81 brute force time \o/ \o/ \o/

Comment: @hyper-neutrino "2^81 brute force time" - uhh, what do you mean ?!

Comment: @Programmer It's a grid of 81 cells so there are 2^81 possible configurations, so I was joking and saying I was going to brute-force all 2^81 possibilities

Comment: Is the grid of infinite size (i.e. boundless) ?

Comment: @astroide Yes, the grid is infinite

Comment: `Each letter has a 5×7 bounding box, with an empty column in between, for a 16×7 overall bounding box` Doesn't 5 (T) + 1 (padding) + 5 (N) + 1 (padding) + 5 (B) give a size of 17×7 ?

Comment: @astroide Note that the B is 4×7, not 5×7